# Change postgresql row field at start and end transaction

Tags: spring, postgresql, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

My stack is postgresql and Spring jdbc and I have table with columns like this:

```
|Id|     work_data       |work_status|

|1 |{"somevalue":"value"}|    NEW    |
```

Question: What is the best and elegant solution will be to change `work_status` from NEW to IN_WORK at the beginning of transaction (within transaction) and if transaction is completed successfully change `work_status` from IN_WORK to COMPLETE or if transaction rolled back then change `work_status` from IN_WORK to ERROR within transaction?

I have research for something transactions can do with this situation and not found much information but only savepoint, but it doesn't seem a good solution with savepoint.

Comment: check [TransactionalEventListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html). refer this [TransactionalEventListener github sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26974#issuecomment-848640269)